# Rails Arel - how to do INTERVAL 1 DAY with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arel

In a Rails 4 app using [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel), how would I construct the following part of a `WHERE` clause?:

```
stopped_at < DATE_ADD(DATE(started_at), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

I have the following already:

```
started_at_date = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('DATE', [arel_table[:started_at]])
next_day = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('DATE_ADD',
                                          [started_at_date, 'INTERVAL 1 DAY'])
conditions = arel_table[:stopped_at].lt(next_day)
```

The problem is that INTERVAL 1 DAY gets quoted:

```
>> conditions.to_sql
=> "`my_table`.`stopped_at` < DATE_ADD(DATE(`my_table`.`started_at`), 'INTERVAL 1 DAY')"
```

MySQL does not like it being quoted, so I need to tell Arel not to quote it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SqlLiteral](http://rdoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/Nodes/SqlLiteral) was what I needed:

```
started_at_date = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('DATE', [arel_table[:started_at]])
one_day = Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('INTERVAL 1 DAY')
next_day = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('DATE_ADD',
                                          [started_at_date, one_day])
conditions = arel_table[:stopped_at].lt(next_day)
```

Comment: Don't know in what version it was introduced in Arel, but there is a short way for e.g. `Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('INTERVAL 1 DAY')`, it's `Arel.sql('INTERVAL 1 DAY')`, can be good to know.